# Developer license alternative in Windows 8.1 store app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, licensing, windows-8.1-universal

I have a windows store app for Windows 8.1 - it's a specific app that is supposed to run only at one device. I deliver it to client via AppDevPackage and it's installed / updated via Power Shell script.

The app works fine when developer license is valid on the device but this license shouldn't be used in production enviroment. Also there is need to renew this license occasionaly (that's very inconvinient).

I know that's obsolete technology, but my question is, what should I do to get rid of the need of having developer license at this device (and to keep posibility of publishing the app via AppDevPackage)?

Please help ;)